# Regex Matching Optional Parameters with same groups

Tags: c#, regex

What is the best way to match all these lines.  In the first two lines I will have 3 groups, user/password/mode, but in the last one I would ideally like to have all three groups, but just the value for 3 is an empty string.

```
set admin user "user1" password "password1" privilege "all"
set admin user "user2" password "password2" privilege "all"
set admin user "user3" password "password3"
```

My current regex only matches the first 2.

```
set admin user "(?<user>[\w-]+)" password "(?<password>.*)"(\s+privilege\s+"(?<mode>[\w-]+)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set admin user "(?<user>[\w-]+)" password "(?<password>.*?)"(\s+privilege\s+"(?<mode>[\w-]+)")?
```

the trailing `?` makes the last group optional

Comment: You should also make the password pattern lazy (`(?<password>.*?)`), otherwise it'll always grab the privilege too.

Comment: yes, this worked.  I know I tried the question mark and it made my groups 1-6 instead of 1-3.  I must have had the parenthesis messed up?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `?` as an optional group or char.

`ab?` would match `a` and `ab` since the `?` after the `b` indicates that a char or group is optional.

Another example: `a(abc)?` this would match aswell `a` and `aabc` with an `abc` backreference since you have told the pattern "compiler" that the `"abc"` string is optional.

A really well explained of optional items: [Optional Items in Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)